# Long time execution of the request

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008

Good day!

```
List<TotalServiseCalls> TSC = (
    from scall in contextOMNIDB.UserFields698.AsEnumerable()
    where scall.f2_creationd >= referenceDate
    group scall by scall.f2_creationd.Month into scalls
    select new TotalServiseCalls
    {
        mountN = (from sc in contextOMNIDB.UserFields698.AsEnumerable()
            where sc.f2_creationd.Month == scalls.Key
            select sc.f2_creationd).FirstOrDefault(),
        date = (from sc in contextOMNIDB.UserFields698.AsEnumerable()
            where sc.f2_creationd.Month == scalls.Key
            select sc.f2_creationd.ToString("MMMM yyyy")).FirstOrDefault(),
        totalCount = scalls.Count()
     }).OrderBy(p => p.mountN).ToList();
```

MSSQL server has a lot of applications, its load is very high.
This query is executed for forty seconds. This is because of the congestion on the server or the complexity of the query?

The tables has about ten thousand records, the size of one megabyte.

Comment: You could definitely put `contextOMNIDB.UserFields698.AsEnumerable()` into a variable to speed things up. You are calling it three times.

Comment: Then, this query is executed twice: `from sc in contextOMNIDB.UserFields698.AsEnumerable() where sc.f2_creationd.Month == scalls.Key select sc.f2_creationd`

Comment: @meilke thank you so much! I'm new to MVC 4 and C #, could you recommend a project for learning with good examples?

Comment: There is not THE one book but I can recommend [Pro ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.apress.com/9781430242369) which gives you insight on the language, the framework, unit testing it and so much more. Good read with a practical touch.

Comment: @meilke why don't you write your comments as answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say from the information you gave whether it is the query or congestion. Two things that you could improve:

1. Put `contextOMNIDB.UserFields698.AsEnumerable()` into a variable
2. Put that into a reusable form as well: `from sc in contextOMNIDB.UserFields698.AsEnumerable() where sc.f2_creationd.Month == scalls.Key select sc.f2_creationd`

Here is a possible refactored version:

```
var userFields = contextOMNIDB.UserFields698.AsEnumerable();
List<TotalServiseCalls> TSC = (
    from scall in userFields
    where scall.f2_creationd >= referenceDate
    group scall by scall.f2_creationd.Month into scalls
    select new TotalServiseCalls
    {
      mountN = Helper(userFields, scalls.Key).FirstOrDefault(),
      date = Helper(userFields, scalls.Key).Select(o => o.ToString("MMMM yyyy")).FirstOrDefault(),
      totalCount = scalls.Count()
    }).OrderBy(p => p.mountN).ToList();
```

With the helper method being (I had to use `object` because I do not enough about your business objects):

```
private IEnumerable<object> Helper(IEnumerable<object> userFields, object key)
{
  return from sc in userFields
         where sc.f2_creationd.Month == key
         select sc.f2_creationd;
}
```

Comment: +1 for you for this, but I think there's more efficient way to do this, ust by taking first item from grouping

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to query `contextOMNIDB.UserFields698.AsEnumerable()` 3 times, you can just get first record from group, you can get Month as Key of grouping:

```
List<TotalServiseCalls> TSC = (
    from scall in contextOMNIDB.UserFields698.AsEnumerable()
    where scall.f2_creationd >= referenceDate
    group scall by scall.f2_creationd.Month into scalls
    select new {
        mountN = scalls.Key,
        date = scalls.Select(x => x.ToString("MMMM yyyy").First(),
        // You can use scalls.OrderBy(x => x (or any other order)).First()
        // if you want to get specific date
        totalCount = scalls.Count()
    }
).OrderBy(p => p.mountN).ToList();
```

Here's a simple example:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test1", "2"));
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test1", "1"));
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test2", "1"));
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("test2", "6"));
list.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
    .Select(x => 
            new {
                a = x.Key,
                b = x.OrderByDescending(y => y).First(),
                c = x.Count()
            }
    ).ToList()
```